# assignment of variable after function definition in Python

Tags: python, scope, nested, pycharm

I am new to Python so I am unsure about the difference in variable assignment before or after the function definition.

Specifically, the first example was adopted from Lutz's book.

```
   def tester(start):
        print("inside tester")
        def nested(label):
            print("inside nested")
            print(label,nested.state)
            nested.state += 1
            print("done with nested")

        nested.state = start
        print("done with tester")
        return nested

    F = tester(0)
    F('spam')
    F.state
    F.state
```

The objective of the code is to store the state information without using `nonlocal`.

I am unsure what `nested.state` means here. I am unsure because `nested.state` is used inside `nested()` function (i.e. `nested.state +=1`) and outside `nested()` function (i.e. `nested.state = start`).

I modified the code above to see whether Python accepts assigning variable after function declaration for `nested()` and to see whether there is any concept I am missing relating to `function.variable` call (i.e. `nested.state` call).

```
def tester(start):
    def nested(label):
        print(label, state)
        state += 1  #replaced 'nested.state' with 'state' here
    state = start   #replaced 'nested.state' with 'state' here
    return nested

F=tester(0)
F('spam')
F('ham')
```

Unfortunately, above code generates error `local variable 'state' referenced before assignment`. This tells me that I am missing some concept about `function.variable` (i.e. `nested.state`).

Can someone please help me understand three things:

**I.**  why it is that the code with `nested.state` doesn't generate any error but `state` does?

**II.** what does `nested.state` mean? If `nested.state` is a mechanism to access function's variables, why is it that the call inside `nested()` function also uses `nested.state` and not `state`?

**III.** If `nested.state` is a mechanism to access variable inside function, then why is it that PyCharm fails to show `state` under dropdown when I type **`nested.`**?

I'd appreciate any help. I research SO, and couldn't find any explanation on such problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the first code example worked is because it was *assigning and referencing an **attribute** of the `nested` function object*. The key concept to understand here, is that *Python allows you to assign **new**, arbitrary attributes to objects - **including functions***:

```
>>> def func(a, b):
        return a + b

>>> func(1, 2)
3
>>> func.attr = 5
>>> func.attr
5
```

The first code example takes advantage of this fact by using the `nested` function object to store the necessary state. This is the same concept as using any other object to store the state. It's particularly convenient, however, to use a function since it's readily available.

In the second example, a normal variable is used. Because of this, normal scoping rules apply which means simply that the `state` variable defined in `tester` *is not* the `state` variable being referenced in `nested`. Thus, an error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you're asking a question about scope in Python, ignoring your code, check this:

```
def scope_level_1():
    variable = 'Scope_level_1'

    def scope_level_2():
        variable = 'Scope_level_2'

        def core():
            nonlocal variable
            variable += '_TOUCHED_AND_MODIFIED_BY_CORE'
            print(variable)

        return core()

    return scope_level_2()


scope_level_1()
# 'Scope_level_2_TOUCHED_AND_MODIFIED_BY_CORE'
```

Don't worry about the keyword nonlocal, treat it just as a declaring to make code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

First, remember `a += b` is the same as `a = a + b`. So `a` must exist before getting to the `+=`.

Simply put, in the first example the function `nested` has an attribute called `state` (accessed by `nested.state`). It is an attribute, which means that once you tell `nested` that it has an attribute called `state` (you are doing this in line 9 when `nested.state = start`) it keep that attribute. So, in the first example `nested.state` *exists* when you get to the `+=`.

In the second example, you are declaring a variable called `state` in `tester`, and another variable called `state` in `nested`. The one in `nested` could be called `potato` for all that matters, because it is not the same variable. Therefore when you arrive to the `+=`, the variable `state` does not exist!